# Tuning underfit catboost regressor model with fixed training set

Tags: r, catboost, overfitting-underfitting, catboostregressor

I'm currently using `CatboostRegressor(iterations=500, random_seed=123, cat_features=['month_number', 'day_of_week', 'year'])` for developing a 1-year predictive model at a **daily** level. The predictor variables are time feature `date`, **categorical** features `A1 - A4` (for example, `A1 = Group: 1/2/3/4, A2 = Class: Upper/middle/lower`) , and numerical features `A5 - A7` (for example, `A5 = Price: 100/125.6/132.7, A6 = Age 25/30/31/57`). The response variable is a **continuous** variable, such as `revenue` or `rental price.`

My current model with `CatboostRegressor(iterations=500, random_seed=123)` with two initialized parameters `loss_function = MAE, eval_metric = 'MAE'` mostly underfits the actualized data although the final `MAPE` was around `10%-20%` (so, some overfits offsets the underfits). However, I am unsure how the `MAE` function described in the documentation of Catboost defines the weight `w_i` for each prediction error, as the `MAE` is the weighted average of all the prediction errors. In particular, what do they mean by saying *Use object/group weights to calculate metrics if the specified value is true* (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  I am unable to find any examples on how these weights are set, because if the weights are equally weighted, the model would probably not under-fit?

What I have tried so far to improve the **under-fit** issue  is that I already used almost the *entire* *training* dataset to **train** the `CatboostRegressor(),` it is not a feasible option for me to increase training size (since the model needs to be trained fast enough in production environment). The most potential option now is to increase the number of iterations from `500` to `1000`, although I tried this option but it did not help improve the `MAPE.`

**Question.** Is it true that default parameters of `CatBoostRegressor()` would change dynamically based on the dataset? What is the recommended value to tune the `learning rate` and `number of trees.` Also customize the `loss_function` and `eval_metric` to cope with `underfit` issue? The tutorial provided for writing custom loss function is quite complicated that I couldn't follow, so any other tangible examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody could help give some thoughts on this problem?